# web service number of requests running on IIS 7

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

I want to know if there is anyway to determine how many calls per second are made on a WebMethod in my webservice?
Thanks

Comment: That's what exactly you should do in your own logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do so. Options:

- process IIS logs
- add custom perf counters for your particular method
- add tracing and process resulting logs.
- if it is the only call made to your server than existing perf counters can be used.